# Side-By-Side Configuration Error VC90.CRT

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, dll

I keep receiving the following error when trying to run MikTeX 2.8 or Visual Studio 2008 on 64-Bit Windows Vista. It's particularly odd because both programs were working problem free until a few days ago.

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail.

Opening the Application log provides the following information:

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin\texworks.exe". Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.MANIFEST" on line 4. Component identity found in manifest does not match the identity of the component requested. Reference is Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.4148". Definition is Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.1". Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

It looks like the problem is with Microsoft.VC90.CRT.MANIFEST, but I am not sure why or how to fix this problem.

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling Visual Studio and MikTeX, as well as uninstalling/reinstalling Microsoft's C++ Redistributable, but nothing seems to be fixing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that updating to the latest version of AnhkSVN for Visual Studio caused this problem. By uninstalling AnhkSVN this problem was solved.